# How to apply a function per group in dplyr without having to define a function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let us consider the following dataframe

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(v1 = c("a","a","b","b"), v2 = c("X","Y","Y","X"))
```

For the "a" group, the v2 column is in the order (X,Y), which I consider the correct order. By opposition, the "b" group the order is incorrect (Y,X).

Using dplyr and the do() function, I can check for each group, whether the order is correct or not:

```
filter_fn <- function(my_row){
  iX <- filter(my_row, v2 == "X")$i
  iY <- filter(my_row, v2 == "Y")$i
  res <-  as.logical(iX < iY)
  return(data.frame(res))
}

d %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
  do(filter_fn(.)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But to avoid the multiplication of functions, I want to have the logic directly written in the dplyr chain. I have tried with group_map and group_modify:

```
d %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
  group_map( ~ {
    filter(.$v2 == "X")$i < filter(.$v2 == "Y")$i
  })
```

But apparently my understanding of group_map is wrong.
In the documentation I don't see how a function can be used in do(.) without having to be previously defined as function per se.

The expected output would be a following dataframe

```
v1 res
a   TRUE
b   FALSE
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I just edited the question to add more info

Comment: Wouldn't this assume that all groups have the same number of elements and unique values?

Comment: indeed, this is the assumption

Comment: If there are more than 2 groups, how will the comparison be

Comment: Try `d %>% mutate(rn = str_c('col', rowid(v1))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = v2) %>% transmute(v1, res = col1 < col2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the correct order, use `match` to get position of `v2` and `diff` to calculate the difference of their occurrence in each `v1`. Make `res` as `TRUE` if the order matches.

```
library(dplyr)
correct_order = c('X', 'Y')

d %>%
 group_by(v1) %>%
 summarise(res = all(diff(match(correct_order, v2)) > 0))

#  v1    res  
#  <chr> <lgl>
#1 a     TRUE 
#2 b     FALSE
```

Comment: I chose this solution for its shortness and its use of simple intermediate functions.

Answer (score 0):

We can either reshape to 'wide' format and then do an elementwise comparison for each of columns

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
d %>% 
    mutate(rn = str_c('col', rowid(v1))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = v2) %>% 
    transmute(v1, res = col1 < col2)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  v1    res  
#  <chr> <lgl>
#1 a     TRUE 
#2 b     FALSE
```

---

Or another option is to have an `ordered` variable, then grouped by 'v1', check whether `all` the `levels` of the variable is equal to the `unique` values in an elementwise comparison

```
d %>%
   mutate(v2 = ordered(v2, c('X', 'Y'))) %>%
   group_by(v1) %>%
   summarise(res = all(levels(v2) == unique(v2)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  v1    res  
#  <chr> <lgl>
#1 a     TRUE 
#2 b     FALSE
```